# How to create an anchor in Jetpack Compose Web?

Tags: kotlin-js, compose-multiplatform, jetbrains-compose, compose-web, jetpack-compose-web

How to create the equivalent compose code for an HTML anchor tag?

HTML code

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```